# Search in json using JSONPath on the basis of a search parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonpath

I have a Json let say

```
{
"store": {
    "book": [
        {
            "category": "reference",
            "author": "Nigel Rees",
            "title": "Sayings of the Century",
            "price": 8.95
        },
        {
            "category": "fiction",
            "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
            "title": "Sword of Honour",
            "price": 12.99
        },
        {
            "category": "fiction",
            "author": "Herman Melville",
            "title": "Moby Dick",
            "isbn": "0-553-21311-3",
            "price": 8.99
        },
        {
            "category": "fiction",
            "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien",
            "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
            "isbn": "0-395-19395-8",
            "price": 22.99
        }
    ],
    "bicycle": {
        "color": "red",
        "price": 19.95
    }
},
"expensive": 10
}
```

I have a search parameter which a user enter based on my json keys's values. I need to check whether the search parameter appear in my json or not using JSONPath. My Json could contain another json array or object so i have to seacrh through all of them. Is there any faster way available to search through json ?

Comment: user only enter a string to search we dont have any knowledge to which key  it belong to

Comment: Can't you do `$..userInput ` ?

Comment: we can get user input but we dont know to which key that value corresponds to

Comment: You can't search by value using only JSONPath